# meteortesting mocha --full-app is executing 0 tests

Tags: node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have meteor app which is based on wekan `https://github.com/wekan/wekan`.

I have written some tests which are in the `/test` directory.

For my tests i use `https://github.com/meteortesting/meteor-mocha`

When i run `meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha` the tests run but fail because my code is not fully loaded.

So i tried to use the `--full-app` parameter. Now the app code loads and runs somewhat complete, but 0 tests are executed.

What is wrong here?

How can i execute my tests with all the code?

Comment: Is your test main module (usually `tests/main.tests.js`) correctly linked in the `package.json` and does it import all necessary test files?

Comment: Aaah... i think that did the trick. I need to verify it a bit, but i guess you can put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read this question quite often, so let me pick this apart, because there are multiple ways of doing things. Btw - if you have a new project, chances are high you're already avoiding eager loading.

### Eager loading

This option was introduced in Meteor 1.3 and has been the default option ever since.

When running `meteor` or `meteor run` in this mode, all files excepted of those in the folder `/imports` are loaded automatically. There are also a few other rules to it, all can be found on this page: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order

When running tests in this mode, different rules apply and in fact no files is loaded that do not match the following expressions:

- `meteor test` only loads files matching `*.test[s].*`, or `*.spec[s].*`
- `meteor test --full-app` only loads files matching `*.app-test[s].*` and `*.app-spec[s].*`

Additional files can (as you're used to) be imported as usual. All this can be found on this page: https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#test-modes

### Avoid eager loading

Since Meteor 1.7, following a discussion of how to get rid of this special `/imports` directory (https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/135), a new way was introduced:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9690
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9714

When a section like the following exists on the `package.json` file of your project, Meteor will load only those files in the respective modes:

```
"meteor": {
  "mainModule": {
    "client": "client/main.js",
    "server": "server/main.js"
  },
  "testModule": {
    "client": "client/tests.js",
    "server": "server/tests.js"
  }
}
```

In this mode, you can differ between tests and full-app tests by `Meteor.isAppTest()`.

*If a section doesn't exist, eager loading is used instead for this section. We in our projects use eager loading for tests but prefer a non-eager way for the main application. Therefore we only define the `mainModule` section, but not the `testModule` section.*

Sadly, those details are not well presented in the Meteor Guide. They can be found in the release notes of Meteor 1.7: https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#changes-21

Hope this helps and gives a better insight of how loading of files works.