# fs.writeFileSync Can't set DOCTYPE here

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

This Meteor code uses `fs.writeFileSync` to save a file to disc with the html extension, it saves the file OK but I get the following server error

> While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser):
> screen_shots/page.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for
> you)

And the following browser console message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Any idea how to fix this error? Thanks

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); //maybe change const to let
const fs = require('fs')
//.... SOME CODE HERE...
let searchLink = await page.$('input[alt="Search"]')
await searchLink.click()

await page.waitForNavigation()
const html = await page.content()
fs.writeFileSync("/screen_shots/page.html", html, 'utf8') //removing utf8 did not eleminate the error
```

Comment: The first error sounds like you might have some server-side process that watches for new files and attempts to compile them using a template compiler and it's trying to do that on the new `/screen_shots/page.html` file you just wrote, but it's not a valid template so it gets an error.  The second one sounds like someone is trying to parse some JSON, but it's not legal JSON.

Comment: Also, have you looked at what is in `/screen_shots/page.html`?  Does it look like valid HTML?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes it appears to be a valid HTML from a reputable agency and it opens correctly in a browser. I noticed the error happens whenever the app starts if the file is present but the error goes away if the file is not present.

Comment: Again, that sounds like you have some template recompile process that runs on server startup and it's finding this file which is not a template.

Comment: You appear to be writing to an absolute location, "/screen_shots/page.html", I am going to assume that's intended. If that folder is inside your Meteor project source folder, Meteor will detect the change and do a rebuild, and the HTML file you have retrieved isn't a proper template, which is probably what's causing your error. You could try writing to a location that is outside your source tree to confirm that theory.

Comment: @Mikkel Yes that is correct. Moving the location outside the source tree fixed the problem. Howerver it was not a problem when files with extension "png" were saved to location inside the source tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of `/screen_shots/page.html` is in your source tree, which causes Meteor to start rebuilding, and abort what it's doing. You definitely don't want this. Meteor watches all source files that are explicitly imported, but also anything in `client` and `server` folders.

> When running meteor or meteor run in this mode, all files excepted of those in the folder /imports are loaded automatically. There are also a few other rules to it, all can be found on this page: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order

There is more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116026/517914

The `.png` files you also wrote in the same folder will also be loaded automatically, but won't cause errors.

### You probably don't write to the file system

Now that you understand what's going on, you may want to avoid writing to the file system. There are a few reasons for this

1. When using docker, the local file system is read only by default
2. You can attach a volume, but you need to attach it to each server in your scaling group
3. Volumes get full
4. S3 (or similar) is more convenient, and you can apply policies and permissions to the files